# Partial ordering of events in distributed system in practice

Tags: php, event-handling, domain-driven-design, distributed-system, messenger

We are using Symfony Messenger with Amazon SQS as message queue. We have no guarantee that events will be processed in same order as they was dispatched.

**Example**

We have `Payment`:

```
class Payment {
    public static function create(): void;
    public function setAsCharged(): void;
    public function setAsFailed(): void;
}
```

We receive set of actions that happened on `Payment` in one batch and dispatch them to queue:

```
$actions = [
    ['initialization', '2023-01-01 00:00:00'],
    ['charge', '2023-01-01 00:00:10']
];
foreach ($actions as $action) {
    $messenger->dispatch(new PaymentEvent($action)));
}
```

**Current implementation**

Events are dispatched to message queue in order, but as SQS works, `charge` event can be processed before `initialization` event.
We are throwing exception because `Payment` does not already exists. Message is then retried by retry mechanism. Meanwhile `initialization` event is processed on different worker. `charge` is retried, `Payment` already exists. Everything is good. `Payment` is in correct state.

**Problem**

This is not recommended behavior. Exception should not be used to control application.
Moreover we can not distinguish between events that really failed and events that failed because of `Payment` creating takes too long.

**Observed solutions but very complex**

I have studied some algorithms for achieving partial ordering in distributed systems such as: Lamport timestamp, Paxos, Raft

If I understand them correctly, workers must somehow communicate between each other. Should we use Redis, MySQL or any other persistent storage, that can be accessed by all of the workers?

We are using PHP and I didn't find any examples or libraries with implementation to use. It looks like it is very complex problem and it is not worth it. Especially if we can use retry mechanism.

**We do not want to use FIFO queue because of lower performance.**

**Another solution we are trying**

We are currently trying to use process managers to address that problem. With them we can save event to something like buffer and when expected message is received and processed we go to processing another event in buffer.

It starting to come very complex and must be tailored to every domain we modeling.

**Question**

1. Do you think retry mechanism is good enough?
2. Is there any less complex solution that can be used in general?
3. Is there any of algorithm mentioned above suitable for our technological stack?

Comment: Should these be distributed transactions where initialization happens first and then charge is processed?

Comment: Yes, it is distributed transaction. `Payment` is actually event sourced aggregate. Payment must be initialized before charge or fail. Aggregate is persisted into database after any of the event is successfully processed.

Comment: My immediate thought is "Kafka with payment ID as partition key", your tech stack likely has an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

- If you only need a partial (vs. a total) ordering, then it's likely you can have as many FIFO queues as needed (up to the number of partitions of possible events such that no two events in different partitions have an ordering requirement) and direct events to the appropriate queue based on the ordering requirements of that event.
- Alternatively, you might be able to exploit some aspect of your domain to represent the not-yet-seen event.  For instance, a `charge` event for a given payment if seen before the `initialization` event, can result in a state that's basically "this payment hasn't been initialized but has been charged".